# rebase changes into a moved directory

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a git repo with a directory structure that used to look like this:

```
outer
|--> inner1
|--> inner2 
...
```

I restructured into so:

```
outer
|-->middle
    |--> inner1
    |--> inner2
```

In between, a colleague has pushed changes to files in `inner1`, which I now need to rebase on my commit and I have conflict merges. All changes would be none conflicting, it's just that the path to the files has changed. 
Rebasing gives me conflicts, since git doesn't recognize the files have moved. I'd like to know if there's a way to configure `rebase` for this.

How's the best way to go about this?

Comment: i'd say rebase yours (the re-layout) on top of his changes.

Comment: That was my first approach, but git can't deal with it, I completed the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is probably the safest:

- Clone your repo locally
- Checkout his version in the clone; create a branch `foo` for this
- Create `middle` like you did in your copy
- Switch to your branch in the clone
- Rebase your changes on top of the commit you just made (`git rebase foo`)

If this works, you can push the changes to your local repo and then push them to the shared repo.

If something breaks, wipe the clone and start again.